# webform save data as new node

Tags: drupal, forms, drupal-6, cck

is that possible? i use drupal 6 and i want to save webform data instad of sending to email to create a new node with fields ive set via new content type

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use CCK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CCK instead of webform is recommend to use.
But if you want, you should write custom module:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (substr($form_id, 0, 19) == 'webform_client_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = '_YOURMODULE_webform_submit';
  }
}

/*
 * Submitting webform
 */
function _YOURMODULE_webform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
// Investigate here $form_state via print_r or dsm (if devel installed).
// How to save node: http://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+programmatically+save+node
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could modify this module, it's for drupal 7.

http://ichormedia.com.au/blog/webform-submissions-nodes/

It allows you to specify which content type you would like to submit Webform submissions to. The module will also create any missing fields for the chosen content type should the Webform be modified.